# Windows RDP connection fails within 30-60 seconds of successful connection

Tags: windows, networking, rdp

Myself and several other users are having issues staying connected through an RDP session to one of our servers.

- Server lives in a subnet behind a proxy (cloud-based)
- Users connect to network via VPN server on opposite side of proxy
- Connections work and do not disconnect when made from server within same subnet
- Issues only happen with this server
- Server OS: Server 2012 R2
- Client OS: Windows 7/10

I've done some research, but most blogs and posts tell me to check my GP settings and I have with no luck.  I've done a packet capture via Wireshark from both sides, but I really don't know what to look for in here.

Edit:
I'm pretty confident that this issue stems from the NAT server. I just can't find any concrete evidence to prove this because I'm connecting to and working in other servers in that subnet just fine.

I have Wireshark installed on both my client and the server, but my exposure to and experience with it is pretty lacking. Any suggestions on what to look for in these trace logs?

EDIT2:
Can anyone shed some light on possible methods to troubleshoot this? I've checked every configuration and security setting I can think of that RDP uses.  I'm currently investigating the possibility of the POODLE fix interfering somehow..

Comment: If you make a connection to a different server from behind the proxy, does the connection break?

Comment: Do the event logs on the server that is dropping the connection provide any information?

Comment: @MarkoPolo I can make a connection to any other server in that subnet without any problems. Those connections remain open until I maually disconnect or my GP settings boot me.

Comment: @SkylerKincaid There are no errors or warnings that would indicate some type of OS or service issue eminating from Windows or RDP itself.

Comment: I did forget to check the Security log though, but I can't imagine that would show anything besides authentication and authorisation information.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  I resolved it by upgrading the driver on my NIC.  Perhaps that will resolve your issue, too.

Comment: I hit that front already with no luck. This is a server running in AWS so I have very minimal control on the hardware/driver front. I checked around for updates to Amazons Citrix tools (found none) and tried adding and connecting to a new NIC (same problem).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with a set of pre-configured policies. I tried many combinations of policy changes, but none rectified my problem. Try to revert to default domain policies (if modified default policies, back them up and restore to default policies using [Dcgpofix](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875588(v=ws.11).aspx)).